# Ajax post request causes 500 internal server error - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In short: 500 internal server error when trying to do a POST request using ajax to a resource controller's method.

Resource CurrencyController:

```
public function ajaxDeleteImage() {
    if ($request->isMethod('ajax')) {
        $path = $request->input('imgUrl');
        $id = $request->input('id');

        $currency = Currency::findOrFail($id);
        $currency->cur_icon = '';
        $currency->save();
        Storage::delete($path);

        return 'Deleted image!';
    }

    return App::abort(404);
}
```

Here's my routes:

```
/**
 * ajax requests
 */

Route::any('ajax-delete-image-currency', 'CurrencyController@ajaxDeleteImage');

/**
 * admin prefix
 */

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('request', 'ReqController');
    Route::resource('currency', 'CurrencyController');
});
```

edit.blade.php - where i created a form with multipart/form-data:

```
here are some form html code...

@section('custom_scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    var thisUrl = $('input[name="image-hidden"]').val();
    var currencyId = $('input[name=id]').val();

    // console.log(thisUrl);

    $('.del-image').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/ajax-delete-image-currency',
            data: {imgUrl: thisUrl, id: currencyId},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("removed image");
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert('Error' + e);
            }
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
@endsection
```

The problem is - i am getting internal server error 500 whenever i press on a button with class `.del-image` (sending post request with ajax).

Also i tried to delete whole method `ajaxDeleteImage` from a controller at all. Nothing happened, same 500 error. Seems like post request cannot reach that method in a CurrencyController.

Maybe i have a problem in my routes? Wrong sorting? I read that i have to move certain methods above resource controllers, so it would work correctly, but that it's not my case.

Please advice something.

Comment: For errors check your `laravel.log` file.

Comment: no errors there..

Comment: trying increasing (or enabling) debug or or verbose logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue with `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67`

So you have to send csrf token with your Ajax request.

Found it with Dev tools -> Network -> then click on the error -> it will show actual response.

Or if you're using Postman - you will see that error in a response.